# update single column taking lot of time and lot of disk space in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I was executed the update query on single column with 10 million records. it is taking lot of time and lot of disk space in postgresql. please find the below query.
"**update test set record_status = 'I'**;"
and my column data type is "**char(1)**"

please suggest me why it is taking lot of time and lot of disk space.

Thanks,
Vittal

Answer (score 5):

In PostgreSQL, an `UPDATE` creates a new version of the row (“tuple”) (see for example [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-SPACE-RECOVERY) part of the documentation).

So by updating every row in the table, you effectively double the size of the table. The old row versions get removed by autovacuum, but the size of the table stays the same (it becomes “bloated”).

The empty space can be reused by future `INSERT`s, but if you want to get rid of it, use `VACUUM (FULL)`.

The long duration is also explained by the many new tuples. Increasing `max_wal_size` may help some by reducing the number of checkpoints that are caused by the statement.